# Escribir la fecha en la primera línea y una cadena incremental en la segunda línea

Tags: php, date

Con este script genero una fecha actual, lo que debería de hacer es que si pasan dos días esta se actualiza, en caso de que no pasaran dos días la fecha no ha de actualizarse.

Ejemplo:
Si cuando se ejecuta el script la fecha es 2020/06/04, el fichero contiene:

> 2020/06/04
>
> Data1.dat

Si cuando se ejecuta el script la fecha es 2020/06/05, el fichero contiene:

> 2020/06/04
>
> Data1.dat

Pero si cuando se ejecuta el script la fecha es 2020/06/06, el fichero contiene:

> 2020/06/06
>
> Data2.dat

Y así sucesivamente, hasta llegar a "Data150.dat", que entonces se reiniciaria a "Data1.dat". Estoy atascado con el código.

```
<?php
    // Variables
    $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');
    $fichero = fopen("musica/musica.txt", "w");
    $dato = strtotime(file_get_contents($fichero));

    if(!isset($dato)){
        fwrite($fichero, $fecha_actual);
        return;
    }

    $ahora = time();
    $fecha_comp = $ahora - $dato;
    $diferencia = round($fecha_comp / (60 * 60 * 24));

    if($diferencia > 1){
        fwrite($fichero, $fecha_actual);
    }

    // Escribir en segunda línea Data1
    $contenido= "\nData1.dat";
    fwrite($fichero, $contenido);
    fclose($fichero);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evita usar `fopen()` y `file_get_contents()` al mismo tiempo, el primero va a impedir que funcione el segundo y, de hecho, la lógica está al revés, primero debes leer el archivo, luego realizar comparaciones y, solo si es necesario, guardar cambios.

Además, `file_get_contents()` debe recibir un nombre de archivo (cadena) como parámetro y le estás enviando el recurso obtenido por `fopen()` y el resultado será un error.

El código está comentado paso a paso, para que sepas qué hace cada instrucción:

```
<?php
// Valor máximo a guardar
$max = 150;
// Saber si se tiene que actualizar el archivo
$guardar = false;

// Valor por defecto para lo obtenido del archivo (fecha, número)
$datos = [date('Y-m-d'), 'Data0.dat'];

$archivo = 'musica/musica.txt'; // Asegúrate que la ruta es correcta
// Verifica que existe el archivo:
if(file_exists($archivo)) {
    // Carga los datos directamente en el array
    $datos = explode("\n", file_get_contents($archivo));
} else {
    $guardar = true;
}
// Ahora ya tienes en $datos la fecha y data (por defecto u obtenidos del archivo)

// Compara la fecha usando strtotime
// Si la fecha es anterior a 2 días o el archivo no existe
if(strtotime($datos[0]) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . " - 2 days") || $guardar) {
    // Usar fecha actual
    $datos[0] = date('Y-m-d');
    // Obtener número, eliminando 'Data' y '.dat'
    $num = str_replace(['Data', '.dat'], '', $datos[1]);
    // Incrementar número
    $num ++;
    // Si el número es mayor al máximo permitido, volver a 1
    if($num > $max) {
        $num = 1;
    }
    // Aplicar formato Data###.dat, las llaves son para delimitar la variable
    $datos[1] = "Data{$num}.dat";
    // Guardar archivo
    file_put_contents($archivo, implode("\n", $datos));
}
// Si necesitas la fecha, usa  $datos[0]
// Si necesitas el segundo dato guardado, usa $datos[1];
```